# Clipping gpkg's using parallel processing and R

Tags: r, sf, geopackage, parallel-processing

I have two large gpkg datasets. I would like to clip one from the other and use parallel processing to speed up the process. However, I receive an error message. Code and error message shown below:

```
#load required libraries
library(sf)
library(future.apply)

#Set up parallel processing
options(future.numCores = 20)
plan(multicore)

#Load the source geopackage
gpkg_source <- st_read("E:/Roads/UK_roadlink_NoPaths.gpkg")

#Load the clip geopackage
gpkg_clip <- st_read("E:/Areas/400m_GB_Dissolved.gpkg")

#Clip the data
gpkg_clipped <- future_sapply(gpkg_source, function(x) {
  st_intersection(x, gpkg_clip)
})

#Combine the clipped data into a single sf object
gpkg_clipped <- do.call(rbind, gpkg_clipped)

#Save the clipped geopackage to a new file
st_write(gpkg_clipped, "E:/Roads/NoPaths_400mCatchment_Clip.gpkg")

#Stop parallel processing
plan(sequential)
```

Error message

```
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") :
no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I have tried to see whether the gpkg is in fact returned as character using

```
class("E:/Roads/UK_roadlink_NoPaths.gpkg")
```

Which returns the following:

```
[1] "character"
```

Both gpkg's load fine in QGIS and ArcGIS Pro and I am able to conduct analyses on them.

Where am I going wrong in my code?

Comment: I suggest to read some manuals and tutorials first. From GeoPackage you need to read a layer https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/spatial_standards_vector/

Answer (score 3):

`future_sapply` works along columns of the data, not rows. Here's using a sample data set generated from `example(st_read); gpkg_source=nc`. If I print the function arg in the loop I can see its the columns...

```
> s = future_sapply(gpkg_source, function(x){print(str(x))})
 num [1:100] 0.114 0.061 0.143 0.07 0.153 0.097 0.062 0.091 0.118 0.124 ...
NULL
 num [1:100] 1.44 1.23 1.63 2.97 2.21 ...
NULL
```

Then if I try and do `st_intersection` in the function I get something like your error:

```
> s = future_sapply(gpkg_source, function(x){st_intersection(x)})
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

In this case I get a message about "double" and "numeric" because the first column is numbers - maybe your first column is a character variable which would explain your error message.

It seems you want to loop over *rows* instead. Run the loop over 1 to the number of rows using an `lapply` version and extract the row inside the function. Here's a trivial "intersect yourself" operation:

```
> s = future_lapply(1:nrow(gpkg_source), 
         function(i){
            st_intersection(gpkg_source[i,], gpkg_source[i,])})
```

The output is a list that you can then `rbind` up into a spatial data frame:

```
> out = do.call(rbind, s)
> out
Simple feature collection with 100 features and 28 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
First 10 features:
    AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
1  0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
2  0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0
```

Your investigation into `class("E:/Roads/UK_roadlink_NoPaths.gpkg")` is a red herring. That returns "character" because you passed a character string in quotes. You could try `class(st_read("E:/Roads/UK_roadlink_NoPaths.gpkg")` which will tell you its a spatial data frame.